# bar button item segue not adding navigation bar at top of next view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When I drag to the next view controller to add a segue the new view controller has no navigation bar with a back button. I thought that was the default when you add a segue to a new VC. I'm also not able to drag a navigation bar to the top of the table view controller. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is the kind of segue that you are you using. The Segue type should be "Show (e.g Push)". Click on the segue and in the right panel go to the "attributes inspector" (the 4th one). And here you can check the type.

Comment: yeah it is the show segue, I tried opening a new project and it works fine from that one.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller like in your case only shows a navigation bar by default, when the view controller itself or one of its parents (connected by a push-segue) is embedded in a navigation controller. Obviously, the navigation controller must not have hidden the navigation bar.

So, you either forgot to put a navigation controller into play or your segue is modal and not push.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's two years since you asked your question, but when it happened to me, I realized it was because at one point, I had accidentally created my segue as a different kind of segue (a detail one, I think), but changing it back to a "Show" segue didn't actually change it's behavior. When I found the segue in my storyboard xml, it was listed as a "Show" segue, but with a different custom action that suggested it was going to do something completely different.

Anyhoo, deleting and recreating the segue in Xcode fixed it. I probably could have also deleted that custom action in the xml file, too.